# Python Dictionary - iterating to retrieve values from exact keys out from JSON response into sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, list-comprehension

I'd like to try and fix my script to tidy up the output to something ordered and readable.
I have a JSON response with the values I need to collect into a separate list (called new_report below). The JSON list with dictionaries looks like this:

```
json_op = [{'Group': '1', 'hostname': 'host2', 'sw_version': '2.08', 'bios': '1.214'},
 {'Group': '2', 'hostname': 'host45', 'sw_version': '2.15', 'bios': '1.224'}, 
 {'Group': '3', 'hostname': 'host23', 'sw_version': '2.10', 'bios': '1.254'}, 
 {'Group': '4', 'hostname': 'host100', 'sw_version': '2.20', 'bios': '1.234'}]
```

I have written the following to iterate through it and retrieve the values for 'hostname' and 'sw_version' into a new dictionary:

```
new_report = []
for item in json_op:
    keys = ['hostname', 'sw_version']
    hostname_report = {item[x] for x in keys if x in item}
    new_report.append(hostname_report)

print(new_report)
```

Current Output is a list of sets:

```
[{'2.08', 'host2'}, {'host45', '2.15'}, {'2.10', 'host23'}, {'2.20', 'host100'}]
```

I'd really like to achieve this though (the sequence does not matter as long as the hostname, sw_version format is maintained):

```
 [{'host2', '2.08'}, {'host45', '2.15'}, {'host23', '2.10'}, {'host100', '2.20'}]
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong with the list comprehension in my code?

Thanks

Comment: sets are unordered, how about using tuples/lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Python, `set`s do not maintain order.

You can simply use tuples instead:

replace `{item[x] for x in keys if x in item}` with `tuple(item[x] for x in keys if x in item)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it into a list of lists this way you will maintain the order by that you will be able to make a nested list comprehension.

```
json_op = [{'Group': '1', 'hostname': 'host2', 'sw_version': '2.08', 'bios': '1.214'},
 {'Group': '2', 'hostname': 'host45', 'sw_version': '2.15', 'bios': '1.224'}, 
 {'Group': '3', 'hostname': 'host23', 'sw_version': '2.10', 'bios': '1.254'}, 
 {'Group': '4', 'hostname': 'host100', 'sw_version': '2.20', 'bios': '1.234'}]
keys = ['hostname', 'sw_version']
new_report = [[i[x] for x in keys if x in i] for i in json_op]
print(new_report)
```

Ouput

```
[['host2', '2.08'], ['host45', '2.15'], ['host23', '2.10'], ['host100', '2.20']]
```

Comment: I am getting a "name 'keys' is not defined" error. Have you tested your answer?

Comment: Now there are the keys list

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood the original response. Thanks